# Test service Rspec always return empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

My service work perfectly testing manually, but I need write service test. So I create service test in rspec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReadService do
  describe '#read' do
    context 'with 4 count' do
      let!(:object1) { create(:obj) }
      let!(:object2) { create(:obj) }
      let!(:object3) { create(:obj) }
      let!(:object4) { create(:obj) }

      it 'return 2 oldest obj' do
        expect(ReadService::read(2)).to eq [report4,report3]
      end
    end
```

But `ReadService::read(2)` in test return []

When I type this manually

```
ReadService::read(2)
```

it return array with two oldest obj correctly. What do I wrong? I call this service in test not correctly ?

ReadService implementation

```
class ReadService
  def self.read(count)
    objects = Object.get_oldest(count)

    objects.to_a
  end
end
```

Comment: `ReadService.read(2)`?
From your test, ReadService is not a module. Just a class. And you are passing in a fixnum. Maybe post your implementationi of `ReadService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you use `let!`. This helper will only create the object when you first reference it, which you never do in your test. In this case you should rather use a `before :each` or `before :all` block (depending on what your specs do in the `describe` block):

```
before :each do
  @object1 = create :obj
  @object2 = create :obj
  @object3 = create :obj
  @object4 = create :obj
end
```

If you do not need a reference to the objects, you can create them in a loop:

```
4.times { create :obj }
```

Comment: Can I do this in more 'elegant' way ?

Comment: Do you need to reference the individual objects?

Comment: Added a loop to create the objects in the answer. You can put that in a `before` loop if you have multiple tests, or at the beginning of a single test.

Comment: @Kam `let!` always creates the object in a before block -- `let` (without the !) is lazily evaluated only on the first access